# Please, advise me how to replace innerHTML in xhtml+xml for menu script

Tags: xhtml, menu, svg

I have a perl script with svg graphics, it sends from apache in xhtml+xml.
[My script](http://pastebin.com/mmk0HRLp). It is: http://pastebin.com/mmk0HRLp

As you can see I want to have a pop-up menus when mouse moves over svg elements. Items I need to get from onmouseover="downmenu(evt,'ddd','eee')", that is easy, because I can use one menu script and to substitute different items later for different actions.

It will be all right, if not innerHTML, which doesn't work with xml parser.
I tried to implement createTextNode, but it doesn't eat html entities.

I do not want to use jquery + UL/LI because I have many menus (about 20) and I do not want to write ul/li for each of them.

How else I can achieve menu items substitution with onmouseover event?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not correct that innerHTML doesn't work with `application/xhtml+xml` but the string being parsed *must* be a well formed XHTML fragment.

In your code you have

```
code += '<a href="/www.test.com" '+ admin + '>Link<a>';
```

which should be

```
code += '<a href="/www.test.com" '+ admin + '>Link</a>';
```

Note however, that if `admin` or `finfo` contain named character references that are not valid in XML (e.g. &nbsp;) then that will be sufficient to stop innerHTML from working.

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed it a little bit and now script works.